# IIB - ODBC DSN configuration errors (Windows)

Tags: windows-7, odbc, ibm-integration-bus

I previous installed IIB version 9 on Windows 7. The ODBC drivers appear in both "Microsoft ODBC Administrator" (32-bit) and "Data Sources x64 (ODBC)".

I have now installed IIB version 10 (10.0.0.21 Developer edition) alongside it, and the x64 data sources window doesn't show the version 10 drivers.

Additionally, I can create data sources (System DSN) under Version 10.0.0.21 using the 32-bit version of the administrator tool, but when I try to delete the Data Source I get the following messages:

> The setup routines for the IBM Integration Bus 10.0.0.21 Developer Edition - DataDirect Technologies 64-BIT Oracle Wire Protoco [sic] ODBC driver could not be found. Please reinstall the driver.

> Driver's ConfigDSN, ConfigDriver, or ConfigTranslator failed. Errors Found: Component not found in registry

I can create and delete IIB9 Data Sources just fine, using either tool.

The fact that the name of the driver is cut off in the quote implies to me that there is an issue with some max name length being surpassed, but I don't know if that's true or not. I have tried editing the registry to make the name match that seen in the textbox (in accordance with some instructions I saw online), but it just made the driver details change in the 32-bit UI and still not appear in the 64-bit.

In the registry I have the following:

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\IBM Integration (9.0.0.2) - DataDirect Technologies 7.0 64-BIT Oracle Wire Protocol
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\IBM Integration (9.0.0.2) - DataDirect Technologies 7.0 64-BIT Sybase Wire Protocol
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\IBM Integration Bus 10.0.0.21 Developer Edition - DataDirect Technologies 64-BIT Oracle Wire Protocol
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\IBM Integration Bus 10.0.0.21 Developer Edition - DataDirect Technologies 64-BIT Sybase Wire Protocol
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\IBM Integration (9.0.0.6) - DataDirect Technologies 7.1 64-BIT Oracle Wire Protocol
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\IBM Integration (9.0.0.6) - DataDirect Technologies 7.1 64-BIT Sybase Wire Protocol

I assume I need to reinstall the IIB ODBC drivers? - If so, can I do that; and if not, what do I need to do to resolve this?

Comment: Thanks for the clear problem description. I don't have any technical suggestions, but you could try asking the same question on mqseries.net. Failing that, you could ask IBM for assistance (if you have a licensed copy of IIBv9 then I think you are entitled to upgrade to v10 and retain IBM support).

Comment: @kimbert Thanks, I will try mqseries if I get no joy here

Comment: posted at http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=435320

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the driver "IBM Integration Bus 10.0.0.n Developer Edition - DataDirect Technologies 64-BIT Oracle Wire Protocol" is too long for Windows to cope with.

You have to go into the Registry and replace it with a shorter name, everywhere that name comes up.
It'll fix this issue and all DSNs will work again.

Registry paths for changing:

- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources (modify)
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI (rename)
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers (modify)

[screenshot Registry Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14Ksu.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I also renamed the Sybase one, not that I'm using it - but great first answer